# Youtube fullscreen icon disabled in html widget at flutter

Tags: flutter

I created a native example and am using html widget.
the package i use:https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_html

There is a youtube video in the html code that comes, but the fullscreen button is disable. I want to watch and watch this full screen.

how can i do it, i will be very happy if you help.